# can I use global constant in <style> section?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuex

I would like to use global constant for css style. for example,

table td {
 border: 1px solid mycolor
}

can I define mycolor in other file such as config file? so that I can change actual color by color theme.

Comment: How about using variable classes in the template?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean global CSS variables and yes you can but be mindful of browser support. If you're using a pre-processor like SCSS, you can define and share variables too.

#### CSS Variables

```css
:root {
  --color: red;
}
```

and your Vue component style block:

```
<style>
.some-class {
  color: var(--color);
}
</style>
```

An example with SCSS

#### SCSS Variables in a file for example: `/assets/vars.scss`

```css
$color: red;
```

and your Vue component style block:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "~/assets/vars.scss";

.some-class {
  color: $color;
}
</style>
```